# Why is a weight automatically a complex weight?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

EDIT: I think the partial answer to my question is that in order to talk about weights we always need a complex Lie algebra. If the Lie algebra is real, we use the complexification, This is necessary, because otherwise the Chevaller/Cartan Weyl basis does not exist and we don't have roots that act as ladder operators etc. All finite-dimensional semisimple complex Lie algebras have a Chevaller-basis.

Nevertheless, it would be great if someone with more experience could help me understand these things a bit more clearly

---

In the appendix A page 20 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9803139.pdf) the authors write

> ...complex
>   weight   [ $| (1 / 2 , \sqrt{3/2}) \rangle$], which cannot be accomplished with a single hermitian matrix

What do the authors mean by this? Why is a weight of the adjoint representation automatically complex and why doesn't correspond it to a singlet hermitian matrix?

I thought the adjoint representation is always real and thus the weights should correspond to real matrices.

On the next page they refer to the combination  $| (1 / 2 , \sqrt{3/2}) \rangle + | (-1 / 2 , -\sqrt{3/2}) \rangle $ as "real combination".

**Why do we need to add two weights of the adjoint representation in order to get sth real?**

---

As an example take $\mathfrak{su}(3)$. We write the adjoint $8$ as a $3 \times 3$ matrix because $3 \otimes \bar 3= 1 \oplus 8$. Then components are given through the tensor products $ 8_{ij}= 3_i \otimes \bar 3_j$, where we add the $i$-th weight vector of $3$ to the $j$-th weight vector of $\bar 3$. This yields the matrix
$$ 3 \otimes 3= \left(
\begin{array}{ccc} \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\\end{array}\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\\end{array}\right) & \left(\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\end{array}\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This tells us, for example, that the weight $( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\\end{array} )$ corresponds to the matrix

$$\left(  \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right) $$

which I would call a real matrix.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by weights corresponding to real matrices. Can you clarify? I would define the weights of a real representation to be the weights of its complexification. You need to perform this complexification to guarantee the existence of eigenvectors.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I made an edit to the question to explain what I have in mind. The matrix was too big for a comment.